# What topological shape is this game board?

Tags: general-topology

In the turn-based strategy video game, [Advance Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_Wars), players are able to create their own game boards. The boards are 2D grids composed of discrete tiles with various "movement costs". Thinking of this as a graph, the "movement cost" of a tile represents the distance *from* all adjacent tiles.

However, a bug-turned-feature discovered by the game's [PvP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Player_versus_player) community's board designers is that a hacked/crafted null tile would be rendered as a black square, and have a movement cost of $0$. This was dubbed the "teleport tile" and used to various effects.

One such effect, depicted here, is to create a map for which all edge tiles (ocean tiles in this case) are distance-$1$ from each other, but is otherwise a conventional 2D "plane":

[image: Advance Wars By Web: 12P - Immigration (Teleport)]

What would a topologist call this? I'm inclined to say it's a "sphere": with one pole being represented by the black edge, but I'm not educated on the topic enough to say. (No units may end their turn on the black squares, so you may consider them not to be genuinely "part of" the board if it would yield a more elegant answer. Their chief effect is that any tiles adjacent to a contiguous region of them become "adjacent" to one another.)

Comment: The reason I'm asking here is that I had *guessed* it's a sphere, but an acquaintance in a mathematics group I'm in had said it's a [cone](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpaceCone.html) of a plane. Is that the same thing as a sphere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, that's a sphere.

You can tell, because if you take a journey on the map that leads you back to the starting point, then you can shrink that journey down to a single point:

- if your journey doesn't touch any black squares, this is obvious, since without the black squares, you have a loop on the plane.
- Suppose it touches black squares, entering at black squares Ai and teleporting to black squares Bi before venturing to the interior, you can shrink the path to eliminate some pair Ai and Bi, by replacing the teleport with a journey around the edge, just skirting the black squares, leaving a journey that touches fewer black squares.

So, by the Poincare conjecture, it's a sphere: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture

Comment: > _if you take a journey on the map that leads you back to the starting point, then you can shrink that journey down to a single point_ < Isn't this also true of a "boring, normal" finite rectangular plane [rectangular gameboard] that contains no holes [no impassable terrain]?

Comment: You are correct that normal boring gameboards have shrinkable loops. 

Poincare's conjecture states that *compact* manifolds with *no boundary* and shrinkable loops are spheres. 

This gameboard is compact, and has no boundary. 

Normal boring gameboards have a boundary.

Infinitely large game tables are not compact.